# Generalization of (vertex) coloring of a graph to hypergraphs

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, hypergraphs

I'm wondering why is the generalization of a coloring of a graph is:

- (The correct one) Assigning colors to vertices of a hypergraph so that no edge with cardinality larger or equal to 2 is monochromatic
- (Why not this one) Assigning colors so that each vertex that is connected by an edge have different color

The "*2 vertices ANNE and BILL has an edge between them, so they have some relation (that we assigned), and thus they must have different colors (represents something else)*" analogue doesn't apply to the definition of coloring a hypergraph, what can I substitute it with?

"*These $k$ people (vertices) are related (thus in the same hyperedge), so we must assign at least 2 different things (colors) for them*" isn't a very good analogy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second generalization (all the vertices on a hyperedge must have different colors) is just a graph coloring problem in disguise. Define a graph by putting an (ordinary, $2$-vertex) edge between any two vertices that are on the same hyperedge. Then we are just trying to find a proper coloring of this graph.

The first generalization, where we only require that the vertices on a hyperedge are not *all* the same color, is a genuinely new problem. Even if it's a bit harder to think of applications for it, this is the only worthwhile definition, because it's the definition of a problem we couldn't talk about before.

(I'm exaggerating a bit; the "rainbow chromatic number" of a hypergraph, where every vertex on a hyperedge has a different color, does see some use. That's because, even though it reduces to a graph coloring problem, it reduces to a graph coloring problem for a special kind of graph that's a union of cliques, and we might still be able to say something about it that doesn't hold in general.)

Comment: Is it so hard to think of applications for it? Isn't Ramsey theory all about chromatic numbers of certain special hypergraphs?

Comment: That's fair, and I am a big fan of Ramsey theory, but I stand by my claim that it's "a bit harder". The graph chromatic number has plenty of immediately practical applications outside pure math, and to get there from Ramsey theory you need a few more steps.

Comment: @MishaLavrov if I may ask, why the number 2 specifically? Is the question "not mono-chromatic", or does it extend to "at least k different colors per hyperedge of at least size k"? The paper is part of my independent reading, but when I ask my professors about hypergraphs they seem to be very mindful of their wording. Is it still in research? If not,  are there any textbooks that cover hypergraphs?

Comment: Yes, the goal of the definition of chromatic number for hypergraphs is "no edge is monochromatic" (excluding $1$-vertex edges because we can't do anything about those). Perhaps the extension to "every hyperedge of size at least $k$ must have at least $k$ different colors" has been studied, but it's not common.

Comment: A classic textbook reference is Berge's *Graphs and Hypergraphs*, which has a chapter on the hypergraph chromatic number.